# Generating triangles with consecutive-integer sides and rational area

Tags: triangles

I'm stuck on this problem for quite some time:

> Call a triangle a *Special Rational triangle* if it's area is rational, and the side lengths are consecutive positive integers, Can we find a closed form which generates all *Special Rational triangles*?

I have tried this one for quite some time, I was able to find a nice closed form in terms of a Diophantine equation, but I'm totally not satisfied with it. Your insight would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Corrected the typo, thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Almost-equilateral Heronian triangles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heronian_triangle#Almost-equilateral_Heronian_triangles)
can be generated using expression for the length of the middle side

\begin{align}
a_n&=(2+\sqrt3)^n+(2-\sqrt3)^n
\quad\text{for }\quad n=1,2,\dots
.
\end{align}

The two other side lengths
are $a_n-1$ and $a_n+1$,
see also [A003500](https://oeis.org/A003500).

Alternatively,

\begin{align} 
a_1&=4,\quad a_2=14
,\\
a_n&=4a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}
.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Let the sides of the triangle be $a,a+1,a+2$ where $a$ is a positive integer.  The perimeter of the triangle is an integer, so we need only be concerned with the area.  The semiperimeter is $\frac{3a+3}2$, so by Heron's formula, the area is
$$\sqrt{\frac{3a+3}2\cdot\frac{a+3}2\cdot\frac{a+1}2\cdot\frac{a-1}2}
=\frac{a+1}4\sqrt{3a^2+6a-9}$$  For this to be rational, it is necessary and sufficient that $3a^2+6a-9$ be a perfect square.

Suppose $3a^2+6a-9=x^2$ where $x$ is a positive integer.  Let $y=a+1$.  Then $$3y^2-x^2=3a^2+6a+3-(3a^2+6a-9)=12$$ so we need the solutions to $3y^2-x^2=9$ in positive integers.  This is a Pell-type equation, and methods of solution are well-known.  I simply typed it into [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%203y%5E2-x%5E2%3D12%20in%20integers).  The positive solutions for $y$ are $$y=\left(2+\sqrt3\right)^n+\left(2-\sqrt3\right)^n$$ so that the solutions for $a$ are
$$a=\left(2+\sqrt3\right)^n+\left(2-\sqrt3\right)^n-1$$

The first few values of $a$ are $$3,13,51,193,723$$  Plugging these into OEIS, we find [A016064](http://oeis.org/A016064), which gives some other formulas and recurrences.

Answer (score 0):

Let the sides be $n-1$, $n$, and $n+1$ for $n \in \Bbb{Z}$ with $n > 0$.  (You don't explicitly reject degenerate triangles with $n - 1 = 0$...)

By [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula), the area is
$$  A = \sqrt{s(s-(n-1))(s-n)(s-(n+1))}  \text{,}  $$
where $s = (1/2)((n-1) + n + (n+1)) = (3n/2)$, so
\begin{align*}
A &= \sqrt{s(s-(n-1))(s-n)(s-(n+1))}  \\
    &= \sqrt{(3n/2)((3n/2)-n+1)((3n/2)-n)((3n/2)-n-1)}  \\
    &= \sqrt{(3n/2)((n/2)+1)(n/2)((n/2)-1)}  \\
    &= \sqrt{\frac{3}{16}n^2(n^2 - 4)}  \\
\end{align*}
By plugging in $0$, $1$, and $2$, we quickly see that $3 \mid n^2(n^2 - 4)$.  With a similar computation, we find $n^2(n^2 - 4)$ is divisible by $16$ exactly when $n$ is even, so $n = 2m$.
$$  A = 3\sqrt{\frac{4m^2(4m^2 - 4)}{3 \cdot 16}} = 3\sqrt{\frac{m^2(m^2 - 1)}{3}}  $$
By plugging in $0$, $1$, and $2$, we quickly see that $3 \mid m^2(m^2 - 1)$, so $\frac{m^2(m^2 - 1)}{3}$ is an integer for any choice of $m$.

So we want to solve
$$  \frac{m^2(m^2 - 1)}{3} = u^2  $$
in integers.  That is,
$$  (m^2)^2 - 3u^2 = m^2  \text{.}  $$
Notice $m^2$ divides two terms, so it divides all three.  Divide through by $m^2$, obtaining
$$  m^2 - 3(u/m)^2 = 1  \text{,}  $$
a [Pell's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation#Generalized_Pell%27s_equation), where we seek solutions in the integers $m > 0$ and $u/m \geq 0$.

By the usual application of continued fractions, we obtain a general solution.  We don't actually need the form of $u/m$, but,
$$  m = \frac{1}{2} \left( (2-\sqrt{3})^c + (2+\sqrt{3})^c \right)  $$
for integer $c \geq 1$.  Then suitable triangles are obtained from all
$$  n = \left( (2-\sqrt{3})^c + (2+\sqrt{3})^c \right)  $$
for integer $c \geq 1$.  (This includes the degenerate $1$-$2$-$3$ triangle when $c = 0$.)